# Missing scripts "watch-tsc" in nodejs

Tags: node.js

When i try to run `npm run watch-tsc`, it give me this:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN>npm run watch-tsc
npm ERR! Missing script: "watch-tsc"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-27T07_29_50_766Z-debug-0.log
```

and in the logs it said:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v18.12.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 5ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ADMIN\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 15ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
21 verbose title npm run watch-tsc
22 verbose argv "run" "watch-tsc"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
27 verbose logfile C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-27T07_29_50_766Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 14ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 35ms
32 silly logfile done cleaning log files
33 timing command:run Completed in 4ms
34 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "watch-tsc"
34 verbose stack
34 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
34 verbose stack   npm run
34 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\run-script.js:98:13)
34 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
35 verbose cwd C:\Users\ADMIN
36 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
37 verbose node v18.12.0
38 verbose npm  v8.19.2
39 error Missing script: "watch-tsc"
39 error
39 error To see a list of scripts, run:
39 error   npm run
40 verbose exit 1
41 timing npm Completed in 55ms
42 verbose code 1
43 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
43 error     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-27T07_29_50_766Z-debug-0.log
```

i did try

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

to see if that would help and run the command again but still not work
here is what it give me when i do `npm doctor`, maybe this will give you more info and can tell me what i'm missing

```
Check                    Value  Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                 ok
npm -v                   ok     current: v8.19.2, latest: v8.19.2
node -v                  ok     current: v18.12.0, recommended: v18.12.0
npm config get registry  ok     using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                ok     C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE
Verify cache contents    ok     verified 525 tarballs
```

i don't know what to do next, can someone give me a suggest?

here is what i think is my package cause when i search it i found alot of package.json

```
{
    "name": "typescript",
    "author": "Microsoft Corp.",
    "homepage": "https://www.typescriptlang.org/",
    "version": "4.8.4",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "description": "TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development",
    "keywords": [
        "TypeScript",
        "Microsoft",
        "compiler",
        "language",
        "javascript"
    ],
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript.git"
    },
    "main": "./lib/typescript.js",
    "typings": "./lib/typescript.d.ts",
    "bin": {
        "tsc": "./bin/tsc",
        "tsserver": "./bin/tsserver"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@octokit/rest": "latest",
        "@types/chai": "latest",
        "@types/convert-source-map": "latest",
        "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
        "@types/glob": "latest",
        "@types/gulp": "^4.0.9",
        "@types/gulp-concat": "latest",
        "@types/gulp-newer": "latest",
        "@types/gulp-rename": "latest",
        "@types/gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
        "@types/merge2": "latest",
        "@types/microsoft__typescript-etw": "latest",
        "@types/minimatch": "latest",
        "@types/minimist": "latest",
        "@types/mkdirp": "latest",
        "@types/mocha": "latest",
        "@types/ms": "latest",
        "@types/node": "latest",
        "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
        "@types/q": "latest",
        "@types/source-map-support": "latest",
        "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.28.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.28.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/utils": "^5.28.0",
        "async": "latest",
        "azure-devops-node-api": "^11.1.1",
        "chai": "latest",
        "chalk": "^4.1.2",
        "convert-source-map": "latest",
        "del": "6.1.1",
        "diff": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "8.17.0",
        "eslint-formatter-autolinkable-stylish": "1.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.3.2",
        "eslint-plugin-no-null": "1.0.2",
        "fancy-log": "latest",
        "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
        "glob": "latest",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-concat": "latest",
        "gulp-insert": "latest",
        "gulp-newer": "latest",
        "gulp-rename": "latest",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
        "merge2": "latest",
        "minimist": "latest",
        "mkdirp": "latest",
        "mocha": "latest",
        "mocha-fivemat-progress-reporter": "latest",
        "ms": "^2.1.3",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
        "prex": "^0.4.7",
        "q": "latest",
        "source-map-support": "latest",
        "typescript": "^4.5.5",
        "vinyl": "latest",
        "vinyl-sourcemaps-apply": "latest",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "es5-ext": "0.10.53"
    },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "gulp build-eslint-rules",
    "pretest": "gulp tests",
    "test": "gulp runtests-parallel --light=false",
    "test:eslint-rules": "gulp run-eslint-rules-tests",
    "build": "npm run build:compiler && npm run build:tests",
    "build:compiler": "gulp local",
    "build:tests": "gulp tests",
    "start": "node lib/tsc",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "lint": "gulp lint",
    "lint:ci": "gulp lint --ci",
    "lint:compiler": "gulp lint-compiler",
    "lint:scripts": "gulp lint-scripts",
    "watch-tsc": "tsc --watch",
    "setup-hooks": "node scripts/link-hooks.js"
  },
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "buffer": false,
        "@microsoft/typescript-etw": false,
        "source-map-support": false,
        "inspector": false
    },
    "packageManager": "npm@8.15.0",
    "volta": {
        "node": "14.20.0",
        "npm": "8.15.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to put `"watch-tsc": "tsc --watch"` line in `package,json` 's `scripts` object.

Comment: @bogdanoff when i search for the package.json, i found alot of them. i don't know which is the one i need to put in

Comment: It means you've no script named as 'watch-tsc' in your package.json file

Comment: @XuanTungDang share your package.json file

Comment: and when i found one that have the scripts object in it, i add it in and it still don't work. i don't know if it was it or not

Comment: @Arman i add it in, could you take a look and see if that is it?

Comment: @XuanTungDang  can you please share the output of   ' npm run ' only?

Comment: @Arman 
`C:\Users\ADMIN>npm run

C:\Users\ADMIN>`
when i run npm run it give me this

Comment: @Arman it blank i surpose

Comment: Are you sure you're running the command  ( npm run watch-tsc ) from the project root directory? please check and verify

Comment: @Arman i run it in command promt, i don't know how to do it in the project root directory, my senior told me to do it like this:
`terminal:`
`npm i`
`npm run watch-tsc`
is it in side the app itself ? because i just got into coding for about 2 months

Comment: i'm doing the setup for intellij, so if it was in side the app could you told me what i need to do to get the terminal?

Comment: @XuanTungDang press   ⌥F12 on macOS, or Alt+F12 on Windows and Linux to open a terminal in the current project directory. Then try again to run the command

Comment: @Arman i think that the solution, thank you so much, but after i run the npm run watch-tsc i can't access the terminal, is it because it still running?

Comment: maybe yes. you can open a new terminal and run the command from that new terminal

Comment: @Arman i got an error again, i think i need to add another script but i don't know what to add with it
`npm run dev`
it said i'm missing the scripts again, what do i need to add with it?

Comment: @XuanTungDang you can write you custom modified command under the script section in package.json file. Check is https://prnt.sc/lOHMpd2RLxLg 

Alternatively you can google how to add a custom command in a package.json file

Comment: @Arman got it, thank you for helping me all the way here, i'll try it now